# Ping not leaving linux VM

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, ping

Firstly, only just learning Linux and networking, so please assume I have minimal knowledge!

Perhaps a week ago I was working on a small python script that involved pinging devices from the Kali Linux terminal, all was working well. Having now gone off and eaten too much food for christmas I have come back and appear unable to ping any devices on the network from the Linux VM now, where as it was working fine before.

I am able to ping from my host windows machine to these target devices fine, tried the linux/windows side by side, windows worked, linux/VM did not. Only thing I think that has changed between working and not working is I installed nordvpn on the VM, I have tested ping with nordvpn on and off, but neither work.

I also ran wireshark as I did the pings from the VM, hoping to see the traffic, but nothing appeared. So I assumed it hasn't even left the VM? Saw the

I have looked at the below areas;

### ifconfig

Ran ifconfig to see if anything jumped out to me.

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.71.XXX  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.71.XXX
        ether 00:0c:29:47:d5:91  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 560  bytes 509247 (497.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 258  bytes 29173 (28.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 22  bytes 1100 (1.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22  bytes 1100 (1.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

nordtun: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.XX  netmask 255.255.0.0  destination 10.8.0.XX
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 76  bytes 17741 (17.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 105  bytes 7587 (7.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

First thing that looked odd to me was that the first three octets of the eth0 IP doesn't match my network, I assume that could cause routing issues or similar?

Also noticed that the inet and destination for the nord portion were the same, which seems odd to me but I assume is right?

### IP tables

Thought I would look at iptables and see if anything was causing the packets to be dropped.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 612 packets, 281K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  843  778K ACCEPT     0    --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            connmark match  0xe1f1 /* nordvpn */
   28 31723 DROP       0    --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* nordvpn */

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 716 packets, 75917 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  944  130K CONNMARK   0    --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            mark match 0xe1f1 /* nordvpn */ CONNMARK save
  944  130K ACCEPT     0    --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            connmark match  0xe1f1 /* nordvpn */
  236 25565 DROP       0    --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            /* nordvpn */
```

Not as master of iptables, but thought maybe the the last chain in the OUTPUT table was causing the icmp pings to be dropped so I removed it and tested the ping command. Still didn't work. I then returned the DROP instruction to the table.

### Route table

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.71.2    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 nordtun
192.168.71.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Nothing here looked weird to me.

### ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:47:d5:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.18.16/24 brd 192.168.18.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.71.129/24 brd 192.168.71.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 416sec preferred_lft 416sec
6: nordtun: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.8.0.48/16 scope global nordtun
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

eth0 has two different IPs under it, the YYY was what was originally on the machine and the XXX was what I added recently to try and resolve the issue.

### ip route

```
default via 192.168.71.2 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.71.129 metric 100 
10.8.0.0/16 dev nordtun proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.48 
192.168.71.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.71.129 metric 100
```

The .71.2 is not on my home network, not sure why it is different but I am assuming its the reason for issues.

### ip rule

```
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
32765:  not from all fwmark 0xe1f1 lookup 205
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Honestly not sure what this is, but I will read up on it a little.

### iptables-save

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.10 (nf_tables) on Tue Jan  2 03:54:30 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [662:290939]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [784:80525]
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m connmark --mark 0xe1f1 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m mark --mark 0xe1f1 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j CONNMARK --save-mark --nfmask 0xffffffff --ctmask 0xffffffff
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m connmark --mark 0xe1f1 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jan  2 03:54:30 2024
```

### ip n

Decided to run `ip n` also and got the below. It clearly doesn't show any devices I know.

```
192.168.71.2 dev eth0 lladdr 00:50:56:fd:a9:30 REACHABLE
```

Tried pinging the above IP from my windows host machine out of curiosity, but got no response, which I don't think is surprising.

### ip route show table xxx

Tried to look up table 205 (as referenced above) but it appears blank. Was able to pull up 205 instead.

```
local 10.8.0.11 dev nordtun proto kernel scope host src 10.8.0.11 
broadcast 10.8.255.255 dev nordtun proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.11 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 192.168.18.16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.18.16 
broadcast 192.168.18.255 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.18.16 
local 192.168.71.129 dev eth0 proto kernel scope host src 192.168.71.129 
broadcast 192.168.71.255 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.71.129
```

Any help, even just pointing me in the right direction, would be much appreciated!

Comment: `First thing that looked odd to me was that the first three octets of the eth0 IP doesn't match my network` -> This is why you aren't able to ping. If the network card is not in the same network as yours, it can't work. Are you using `DHCP` or `static IP` configuration on `eth0` ? - What is the correct IP of your network ?

Comment: Also,  how are you marking packets for NordVPN?   What happens if you flush your iptables rules?     (It is possible that your VM host/hypervisor is performing NAT and is allocating IP's in the range 192.168.71 - which could mean your iP range is a red herring)

Comment: Also "iptables -vnL" might be useful to you in debugging.  the "-v" adds additional information including the packets and bytes each rule has matched and the interface the rule is operating on.   Generating traffic and watching how this behaves can help identify issues.

Comment: @hidigoudi I believe it is static, all my checks (such as using nmcli on eth0) aren't actually giving me information. However something I did forget to mention was on the VM it is set to NAT for networking, so I assume it should be using the host IP? Which isn't what is shown in the main post.

Comment: @davidgo In regards to marking packets I honestly don't know, I just connect to the VPN from the command line. Not heard of marking before your post! Something else to learn! Thanks for the tip on the verbose flag, I have ran it, though nothing stands out to me. Sadly can't paste the output due to character limit. 

I do see that the DROP chain from nordvpn has some packets. As a trail I ran a ping with the -c 5 flag and looked at the iptables again, the dropped number has jumped up by six (though the accepted jumped by 3). But I removed the DROP rule before and had no luck.

Comment: You can edit your post with new information.

Comment: thanks @hidigoudi, I added in the table above.
Also tried to changing the IP on the linux machine to an unused IP from my network, but pings still not being returned. Thanks

Comment: I'd like to see an `ip addr` instead of ifconfig (as ifconfig does not always show all information – nobody has ported it to the new system in 20+ years), and `ip route` + `ip rule` for the routing table. (For iptables, `iptables-save` would be easier to read...)

Comment: You could also add the output of  `wg show nordtun fwmark`

Comment: @A.B sadly the command does nothing, but that might be because I used nordvpn and not wireguard?

Comment: Yes, never mind my comment. You're right.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I have added the outputs, also added ```ip n``` as I thought that might be useful. Another question, (new to site), do I need to tag you or do you get notified of the update to the original post? Thanks!

Comment: I _think_ only the author of the post being commented-to gets notified automatically... Can you also show `ip route show table 205` for completeness? NordVPN is using "policy routing" to have the OS choose between multiple routing tables (one with your original Wi-Fi route for NordVPN itself, and one with a NordVPN route for the rest of the system), and that _may_ be related to the problem. (You might also want to try `ip route get <ipaddr> [fibmatch]` to have the kernel resolve routes towards the address you're trying to reach.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity Thanks for adding some explanation about the policy routing. 
Table 205 doesn't seem to exist, nothing shows when I run the command. Along with that, I just tried to access the web without nordvpn on, and that fails, can't reach google. Also tried ping 8.8.8.8, which didnt work, and ping google.com states `temporary failure in name resolution.`

**edit**: Also, how do you know there are two routing tables? When I run `route` I see one table called `kernal IP routing table` which has a line for `nordturn` interface, but I dont see a second table?

Comment: @u1686_grawity table 205 was blank, but just read that 255 is the 'standard' table so went off and got that for you, hopefully it helps. I will add it to the original post now.

Comment: @RunRenegade: Right, but those are different things, they just happen to have similar table IDs. Table 255 aka `local` is where the kernel puts special "my own address" routes; table 205 is custom and created by NordVPN when you connect. (And the "normal" table that you get from a bare `ip route` is `254` aka `main`. You can see them being referenced in the earlier 'ip route' output.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity Okay, makes sense. Apart from table 205 being blank, that surprises me. Considering it refenced at `32765:  not from all fwmark 0xe1f1 lookup 205`, though I need to go off and read up what all that actually means.

Comment: Read that as `not (from all fwmark 0xe1f1) lookup 205`; it means "if the packet mark is _not_ 0xe1f1, then look in table 205". (The mark is probably set by the VPN software on its "encrypted" packets – and it _might_ be Wireguard; I know NordVPN has that as an option – and you also have some iptables rules that deal with the same mark.) In short, I think it means "if this is _not_ a NordVPN connection packet, then check table 205". Since the table is empty, it should have no effect; it should just continue with the next 'ip rule' rule down... But that 'DROP' iptables rule might catch it.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I have gone off and learnt about iptables and the RPDB and am wondering; would a ping from the CLI be marked by nord? If not, then the RPDB points it to table 205, that doesn't exist to it goes main (254) but that states `default via 192.168.71.2` which is not my home network, would that cause issues? Honestly not sure where this .71 has come from.